# XStream serializable objects

Tags: java, serialization, xstream

I am currently using XStream to serialize some of my objects that don't implement Serializable. Is there a way to tell XStream to use Java's default serialization if the object does implement Serializable and to fall back on XML serialization if it does not? Or would I need to implement a simple layer on top of it to check?

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

This would not be a good idea. Java serialization is a binary representation, XML is a textual representation.

Take `java.lang.String`, for instance. This implements `Serializable`, but clearly you would not want your Strings serialized as binary blobs inside your XML. Similarly for things like numeric types, etc.

XStream has a mechanism for registering custom converters, I suggest you use that. if you choose to serialize binary data into your XML document, you'll need to encode it somehow, e.g. with Base64 encoding.

Comment: Good explanation.  I wasn't really thinking to apply this down the entire object graph. For example, if I try to serialize class X and it is Serializable, then I would serialize it (and its entire object graph) to a binary file (since it is marked as Serializable, I'll assume its object graph is too). If it is not marked Serializable, I would use xml for that object (and its entire object graph). The reason being is that I have a lot of different objects I'm serializing for persistence but some have huge representations for XML and for those data types I'd rather store in another format.